Including CC in Web-To-Case Auto-Response Rules
I'm working on adding CC recipients using case auto-response rules. The case is generated through the API, and we are storing three extra email addresses to be included in the CC during the case resolution process.
I attempted this method, but it doesn't appear to be effective:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000LFkjPSAT
